# How to search with Ransack in one model form in another model in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two models they are

1. Batches
2. Gradings

Here i render batch form in grading model. Now i want to search with batch_number in grading using Ransack how's it possible. Please help how to proceed it.

**Batch.rb**

```
    class Batch
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Autoinc


  field :date, type: DateTime
  field :batch_number, type: String
  field :raw_q, type: Float
  field :hoq, type: Float
  field :w_yeild, type: Float
  field :purchase_center_id, type: Integer
  field :plant_id, type: Integer
  field :species_id, type: Integer
  field :hlq, type: Float
  field :status, type: String
  field :serial_id, type: Integer

  has_many  :gradings , :dependent => :destroy

end
```

**grading.rb**

```
    class Grading
  require 'autoinc'
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Autoinc

  field :quantity, type: Float
  field :count, :type => Float
  field :grade_id, type: Integer
  field :batch_id, type: Integer
  field :variety_id, type: Integer
  field :serial_id, :type => Integer
  # Mongoid AutoInc
  increments :serial_id

  # Associations
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :variety
  belongs_to :batch
  # validations
  validates_presence_of :grade_id,:batch_id,:variety_id 
  validates_presence_of :quantity ,numericality: true, numericality: {:greater_than => 0}
  validates_presence_of :count ,numericality: {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 10, :less_than_or_equal_to => 150}
end
```

**grading.index.html.erb**

```
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Gradings</h5>
                        <%= render :partial => "batches/search"%>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <%= search_form_for @q, url: search_gradings_path, method: :post do |f|%>
                            <div>
                                <%= f.text_field :batch_number_or_purchase_center_name %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
                            <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                  <div id="gradings">

                    <%=render 'list'%>
                  </div>


                  <div id="gradings-paginator">
                    <%= paginate @batches ,:theme => 'twitter-bootstrap-3', :remote => true%>
                  </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```